# C++ regex to search file paths in a string

Tags: c++, regex

I'm trying to parse strings which can contain file paths. 
I'm using C++ with regex library. I'm not that good with regex, here it's the ECMAScript.

I don't know why the string :

> "C:\Windows\explorer.exe C:\titi\toto.exe"

Doesn't matches the pattern (actually it only founds the first one)

> (?:[a-zA-Z]\:|\\)(?:\\[a-z_\-\s0-9]+)+

Do you have a better idea to find every match ?
Thanks!

Here's my code:

```
wsmatch matches;
regex_constants::match_flag_type fl = regex_constants::match_default ;  
regex_constants::syntax_option_type st = regex_constants::icase             //Case insensitive
                                        | regex_constants::ECMAScript
                                        | regex_constants::optimize;

wregex pattern(L"(?:[a-zA-Z]\\:|\\\\)(?:\\\\[a-z_\\-\\s0-9]+)+", st);

// Look if matches pattern
printf("--> %ws\n", path.c_str());
if (regex_search(path, matches, pattern, fl) 
&& matches.size() > 0)
{
    for (u_int i =  0 ; i < matches.size() ; i++)
    {
        wssub_match sub_match = matches[i];
        wstring sub_match_str = sub_match.str();

        printf("%ws\n", sub_match_str.c_str());
    }
}
```

Comment: did you try googling this?  a quick google of 'file paths in string regex' returned several good examples.

Comment: I googled that of course, but I found only matches, not searches in a string. I do not want to validate a string, but search all sub_matches in this string. 
@MikeM : EDIT - No need a . , this is a search not a match.

Comment: Match? would splitting them by spaces do the job?

Comment: No. What if I do this : "C:\program files\somefolder\test.exe C:\anotherone\test2.exe"

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this:

```
.?:(\\[a-zA-Z 0-9]*)*.[a-zA-Z]*
```

I tested it with http://regexpal.com/ and it extracts all file paths.

Comment: Thanks, that works on the paper for sure. 
I tried it with regex library, it still shows only the first match.

Comment: If you try mine, it matches also the 2 (except the extension, but nevermind). I think here it's a matter of C++ regex library...

Comment: in your regex a pattern is missing before ? -> ? matches zero or one occurrence of the preceding character.

Comment: Oh - I am sorry. I was not aware of that.

Comment: You could try another regex lib, like boost regex, if possible.

Comment: isn't boost based on the std lib?

Answer (score 0):

Although regex provided by @mspoerr satisfies example question, but it wasn't great for me in more complex scenarios, therefore I used to write my own.

**Regex:**

```
(\w:)?([\\\w\s0-9_]*)\.\w+
```

**Advanced test string:**

```
C:\Wi ndows\explorer.exe asdasds
 : ad  C:\titi\toto.Heexe
HELLOO : qwefqwfqwf c:\aa.
```

(it matches only two valid file paths)